# Why can't we prove that $X= f^{-1}(f(X))$ in general?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a map. Let $X \subseteq A$, $Y \subseteq B$.

I saw this result that states $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$.

Well to prove that I said the following:

> Let $x \in X$. By definition, $f(x) \in f(X)$. Again, by definition, $x \in f^{-1}(f(X))$. Hence $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$.

I already try a few examples of the other inclusion, i.e., $f^{-1}(f(X)) \subseteq X$ and indeed is false (we can see for example the quadratic function).

But my doubt is why can't we say the following:

> Let $x \in f^{-1}(f(X))$. By definition, $f(x) \in f(X)$. Again by definition, $x \in X$.

It seems that there is something wrong with the definitions that I'm missing. What is my mistake here?

Thank you!

Comment: Take $X=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=sin(x)$ to see that it does not hold. The answer to your question follows.

Comment: What "definition" are you using to say that $f(x)\in f(X)$ implies $x\in X$?

Comment: @astro yes I know it does not hold, but what is the problem with my attempting derivation?

Comment: there could be $x\in A\setminus X$ s.t $f(x) \in f(X)$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ with $X=[0,1]$ and $x=-1$. This shows the implication is false

Comment: @Andrew $f(x) \in f(X)$ does not imply $x \in X$, the thing is in this context $f(x)$ is treacherous since it is actually $y \in f(X)$ and one makes it become $f(x)$ not actually knowing where does that $x$ come from exactly in the domain.

Comment: I think the problem was that I wasn't considering the "injectivity"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x)\in f(X)$ then you can only conclude that there is some $u\in X$ such that $f(x)=f(u)$. If $f$ is injective (on $X$), that is enough to conclude that $x=u$ and thus $x\in X$. But if $f$ is not injective, you cannot conclude that.

The function $x\mapsto x^2$ is a good example indeed.

Comment: Oh I see! That's why functions like the quadratic fail in that. One more question, if the function is objective, then $X = f^{-1}(f(X))$?

Comment: Injective. Yes. You can prove this essentially with the same argument.

Comment: Injective yes I mistyped. I'm going to work on that argument, now it's more clear thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the reasoning that you have employed to prove that $f(x)$ in $f(X)$ implies that $x$ is in $X$ only works when the function $f$ is injective. Observe that $f(x)$ is in $f(X)$ if and only if $f(x) = f(x')$ for some $x'$ in $X.$ Of course, in order to conclude that $x = x'$ (so that $x$ is in $X$), we must have that $x$ is injective.

Comment: So the other result only holds when the map $f$ is injective?

Comment: @Andrew Note that "$f$ is injective" is equivalent to "$f^{-1}(f(\{x\}))=\{x\}$ for all $x\in A$"

Comment: @halrankard got it! Thank you so much!